# Characters hard to substitute with sed

Tags: bash, encoding, sed

(Below since I can't paste the characters I see, `BB` will mean a character that is a square with numbers 0080 followed by a square with numbers 0094 inside).

I've this subtitles file with an ISO-8859-15 encoding that has `âBB` instead of `–` when seen in a text editor.

If I read the file with `cat`, the dash appears normally but if I use the file as it is it will display a `â€”` on the video subtitles.

I tried substitutions with sed, without success:

```
sed 's/âBB/–/g' thisfile > correctedfile
sed 's/â€”/–/g' thisfile > correctedfile
```

I tried it first in the command line and the numbered boxes fail to appear, then I tried it with a script.

I even tried cheating with

```
sed 's/â../–/g' thisfile > correctedfile
```

and it didn't work.

`cat` and `sed` see it perfectly as a –, so I tried

```
sed 's/–/–/g' thisfile > correctedfile
```

but it didn't work either.

Then I tried `recode iso885915..utf8 thisfile` and vice-versa and nothing.

If I do a regular find and replace in `kate`, it fixes it. But since the problem is present in other files I want to solve with a `for; do; done` loop in command line, but for that I need to know how to fix one of them.

Why these solutions didn't work, what am I missing and how to make it work?

Comment: Try viewing the file as sed sees it. Use `sed -n l file' then use those values in a substitute command.

Comment: `cat` and `sed` see it perfectly as a –, then I tried `sed 's/–/–/g'`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: i don't use sed, but what about this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/ ?

Comment: nice, Miroslav, worth trying. now what is the octal equivalents for the square characters I mentioned, I believe those numbers are hex.

Comment: When in doubt, view the hex!  sed and cat do not 'see' characters as anything.  Your terminal is what is interepreting the sequence of bytes as a dash.  To see what is really in the file, do hexdump -C < thisfile

Answer (score 3):

I think that the sed command you are looking for is this:

```
sed 's/\xE2\x80\x94/-/g' thisfile
```

\xE2\x80\x94 is hex for what I assume is the offending character sequence.  (FYI, it is the UTF-8 code for character 2014, a long dash of some kind).  This is preferable to trying to throw special characters directly into a sed command.

If this does not work, use hexdump to find out exactly what the offending bytes are.

```
hexdump -C thisfile
```

Comment: I understood it and that's precisely the character. Alas, I ran the `sed` and it didn't work. The hexdump shows it as '? 200 224', but when I tested in a created text file where I type a dash like this it appeared the same in the hexdump. Same hexdumps, but only those files in ISO-8859-15 have problems when displaying in kate or as subs.

Comment: hexdump -C will not give you question marks.  Nor will it give you octal values.  Are you perhaps using a lowercase c instead of uppercase?  Also, what do you mean it did not work?  It did not modify the file at all, or it did modify the file and the file still will not display right?  Sed can replace any bytes with any other bytes, regardless of encoding.  I understand it is not working for you, but I am not sure what you mean by it not working.

Comment: I tested. Hasn't changed the file at all, meaning it didn't match it.